# Python to send multiple attachment images to email. Now i success to send 1 image only

Tags: python, email

I already success to send 1 captured images to my gmail in python. I want to send more images in one email. Where should i modify the code.

This is my code

```
import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'hello@gmail.com'
password_user = '**********'
email_send = 'hello@gmail.com'
subject = 'Python'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'hello'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('mixed')

fp='1.jpg'
attachment =open(fp,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+fp)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user, password_user)

server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that attaches an image named `1.jpg`:

```
fp='1.jpg'
attachment =open(fp,'rb')  
part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+fp)
msg.attach(part)
```

Repeat the above code (copy and paste) setting replacing `fp='1.jpg'` with `fp='2.jpg'` (or whatever filename you want) to attach an additional file. You could also make a function called `attach_image` where you pass the name of the file and the `msg` parameter so you *don't have to copy and paste*.